# How to create histogram with "zoom-in" feature

Tags: data-visualization

I was impressed by the Reputation histogram on the SE sites allowing one to zoom in to any time interval.  How was it created?

Answer (score 5):

This is a barplot rather than histogram... Anyway, judging from the page source, it is made with [Highcharts JS](http://www.highcharts.com/).